# Caviar Green HDD extremely slow

Tags: hard-drive, performance

I found a 1.5TB drive that was used for backups (those drives have been upgraded to 2TB) that I thought might be good to use as a secondary drive.

I plugged it into a esata port and it seemed to work (couldn't do a real test as it was formatted to ext3 and this computer is running Windows XP) so I plugged it internally, but on boot it was not recognised. I found if I used a molex to sata power adapter it would work but not using the sata power connector itself. (I have an Antec EarthWatts 500W PSU: it should be enough, my graphics card only takes power from the motherboard)

However it took four days to do a slow format.

I found a testing program and it reported a [read speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycoL6.png) of 3.7MB/s:

[image]

My other harddrives performed [the same test at around 100MB/s:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq0ws.png)

[image]

Is this drive stuffed or is there something else I could do?

EDIT:
OK I think it is stuffed: Found this in Event Viewer (along with hundreds of "The device, `\Device\Harddisk1\D`, has a bad block."):

> The driver has detected that device `\Device\Harddisk1\DR1` has predicted that it will fail.  Immediately back up your data and replace your hard disk drive. A failure  may be imminent.

You could probably ignore this post now!

Comment: What "stuffed hard drive" means?

Comment: @Boris_yo  Stuffed is sometimes used to mean damaged, damaged beyond repair or in need of replacement. I believe that the word was used with one of those meanings in the edit.

Comment: @Boris_yo: sorry about using slang. "Stuffed" is indeed similar to "broken" or "damaged beyond repair".

Comment: you should post your last edit as an answer

Comment: I have a WD Green, so does my friend. Both of our drives are dying, and they are about the same age. SMART only shows FAIL/PRE-FAIL values, condition is 0%. The drives are still spinning, and the WD utility shows them 100% intact/perfect (while they are obviously not).

Hence, we can't return them. So yeah. 2 dead WD Green, lying around without any use. (One 500gb and a 1TB drive.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have your answer.  Is the drive still under warranty?  A quick check here should tell.  If so, you may have a new one for little cost beyond shipping.

[WD Warranty](http://support.wdc.com/warranty/index.asp?wdc_lang=en)

Comment: I've started the RMA process. I thought it'd be out of warranty but it was accepted! (Now to send it to Singapore...)

Comment: If you are lucky you may get a larger drive.  It has happened to me a few times.  Often not but when it does it is a nice bonus.

Comment: The cheapest postage I could get was $30 (without insurance, express, registered, etc), which seems a little high for something apparently worth $70. :-(

Comment: I got an email saying the replacement drive has been shipped and I should get it in a few days (shipping from Singapore to Australia). Judging by the product number (WD20EADS) I'm getting a 2TB! 

This whole ordeal has been relatively painless; I'd definitely buy and recommend WD again.

Answer (score 0):

You should get at least 60 Mb/S on a Caviar Green. Try defragging the drive, leaving at least 15% free (so 225 MB).

Comment: It was newly formatted, so no files, so no fragmentation

Comment: Besides, that testing program performs low-level operations and is unaffected by anything on a filesystem.